# In Robot Frame Work How Can we use value returned from one keyword as input argument to other keyword directly(without use of variable)

Tags: robotframework

How Can we use value returned from one keyword as input argument to other keyword directly (without assigning return value to variable)

Currently I am maintaining all Web Elements or Variable names and corresponding xpath in an Excel Sheet. I get XPath using keyword `read_xpath` by passing web element/variable name as argument.

I store the xpath in separate variable then make use of it for other or Next line keyword. Since I need to use a variable for each XPath access, i am trying to find out, whether is there any way to directly use one keyword output as input to other keyword without assigning it to variable.

The main purpose of storing XPath in Excel sheet is to avoid multiple test cases change with single Element XPath change, making just single change on Excel Sheet should be sufficient.

For Example:
 `read_xpath` reads values from a Excel sheet, Excel sheet has two columns, one `variable name` and second one is `xpath`. Function `read_xpath(element)` takes `variable name` as input and gives back `xpath`.

xlread.py file looks like [xlread.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmWXp.png) Excel Sheet look like [Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAQJ9.png)

**sample.robot** file looks as below

```
${login_user_textctrl}=  read_xpath    username_textctrl

clear element text  ${login_user_textctrl}
Input text    ${login_user_textctrl}    admin
```

Now let us check how I used `read_xpath` keyword  in my robot file

I called Keyword `read_xpath` with argument `username_texctrl`, which returns xpath for username text Control which is stored in variable `${login_user_textctrl}`. Now Input Text `${login_user_textctrl}` admin works fine.

For  below code

```
      clear element text    read_xpath     username_textctrl
```

I am getting, clear element text requires 1 argument but two arguments provided, is there any way i can use the the value returned from Keyword(read_xpath) as input to other keyword directly, without assigning it to any variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating your locators from your robot code through an Object Repository is often done when the locators are reused a lot. An alternative implementation paradigm is to use the Page Object Model. An example of such an implementation can be found in the [Robotframework-PageObjectLibrary](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-pageobjectlibrary).

In case you still prefer the Object Repository approach, then using the `Selenium2Library` keyword [Add Location Strategy](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Add%20Location%20Strategy) might be of interest to you. Below is a working example which uses a YAML file as it's OR to fetch the search input box and search button from Google.

**ObjectRepo.yaml**

```
OR: 
 searchbox: '//input[@id="lst-ib"]'
 searchbutton: '//button[@id="_fZl"]'
```

**Robot Script**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Variables    ObjectRepo.yaml

*** Test Cases ***
Yaml Object Repository
    [Setup]    Add Location Strategy    yro    Yaml Locator Strategy
    Open Browser    http://www.google.com    Chrome
    Input Text        yro=searchbox    Robot Framework
    Click Element     yro=searchbutton
    Sleep     3s
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers

*** Keywords ***
Yaml Locator Strategy
    [Arguments] ${browser}  ${criteria}     ${tag}  ${constraints}
    ${xpath}=     Set Variable    ${OR.${criteria}}
    ${retVal}=     Get Webelement    xpath=${xpath}
    [Return]    ${retVal}
```

As you can see the abstraction through a custom locator keyword allows for clearner code and not require you to fetch into a variable for later reuse.

Comment: Above Solution Works absolutely fine. Can i have little bit more details regarding the parameters passed to Yaml Locator Strategy, What are the values for ${criteria}, ${tag} and ${constraints}?. How can I extend Yaml Locator Strategy to accept Link and Id along with XPath?

Comment: In the example the argument `${criteria}` would contain the value `searchbox`, i.e. anything that comes after the `yro=`. The argument `${browser}` will contain a library reference to the active Selenium2Library. This would be of use in case you have a custom python library that uses it. The other two, `${tags}` and `${contstraints}` I have not seen filled in. So I treat them as empty by design.

Comment: In case this reply is the answer to your question, can you mark it as such so that those that find this question in the future know what worked for you.

Comment: i clicked on up arrow button to say it worked for me but its not accepting it, its say it needs at least 15 reputation to display it people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Evaluate` to call python functions directly. Example:

```
${my element to clear}=    Evaluate    read_xpath("username_textctrl")    xlread
```

See the documentation [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate)

(Note: Example is untested and you should check if xlread is in PYTHONPATH, or found at test run time)

Comment: The Code throws error, No keyword with name 'clear element text= .