# Is it possible to set scope of keyword argument in RobotFramework without explicitly using the built-in keyword - "Set <scope> Variable"

Tags: robotframework

I have a keyword like "Click Menu Item" which takes an argument `${menuItem}`.It then clicks on the corresponding menu item making a dynamic locator xpath.
I need to define/set the `LocatorVariables` and their Xpaths in separate `Locators.robot` resource file so that my testcases/keywords are xpaths free.

```
** Keywords ***  
Click Menu Item  
    [Arguments]     ${menuItem}  
    Click Element    ${MenuBarLeft_MenuItem}
```

So I want to accept the variable `${menuItem}` in a Global Scope so that it will be accessible in `Locators.robot` Resource file.

Though, I understand this can be achieved by using below:

```
"Set Global Variable    ${menuItem}    ${menuItem}"
```

but i wanted to know is there an way I can skip this step by automatic defining the scope while accepting the variable in keyword.

Also please let me know if there is a better way to handle dynamic locators for such case.

Answer (score 0):

> i wanted to know is there an way I can skip this step by automatic defining the scope while accepting the variable in keyword.

No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Bryan Oakley is correct. There is no way to dynamically assign the scope. That said, this doesn't mean what you're doing is the only way that results in no replication of element locators.

A few answers that may help you are:

- [Page Object Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brobotframework%5D%20%20page%20object): centralizing by modeling your application's pages.
- [Custom Locator Strategy using an external YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44466777/6152737)
- [Accessing elements located by custom locator strategy with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743216/6152737)
- [Custom Locator using Get Webelement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299312/6152737)